# Ncurses from sources and Urxvt don't get along

Tags: ncurses, rxvt

After installing `ncurses` from sources, my `urxvt` is not functioning well. Opening applications like`ncmpcpp` or `mutt` will give me

```
Error opening terminal: rxvt-unicode-256color.
```

Also opening `zsh` on `urxvt` will give me weird keypress behavior, like `backspace` inserting a space and moving right (even though it actually erased that character in the buffer).

`xterm` is working perfectly, so the my conclusion is that `ncurses` is not working on `urxvt`. But it did work before installing from sources.

Inspecting the default configuration for `ncurses` build, it already marks `rxvt` as a fallback, so I don't know what else to do. I've also tried to run the minimal `demo` from the `libcurses++` source and it also failed to open.

*How can I make sure that `urxvt` and `ncurses` will be friends?*

> **UPDATE**: I got everything working again by forcing a reinstall from the package repositories.
>
> `sudo apt-get install ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-doc ncurses-examples ncurses-hexedit ncurses-term --reinstall`
>
> which pretty much confirms it was a problem with the compiled installation. I still want to know what is missing in the build and install process that will make it work with `urxvt`.

Answer (score 1):

`urxvt` provides its own terminal description, which you can compile with `tic`.  Since you're compiling `urxvt` from source, that's in its [`doc/etc` directory](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/tree/master/doc/etc).

For instance, assuming you have [rxvt-unicode.terminfo](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/doc/etc/rxvt-unicode.terminfo)
, then

```
sudo tic -x rxvt-unicode.terminfo
```

will fix your problem.  Debian adds this in their patches for ncurses, but it is not part of the upstream source.

Further reading:

- [Where is rxvt-unicode?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_urxvt) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Re: [REQ] Add rxvt-unicode terminfo](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2009-10/msg00031.html)
- [Fwd: [REQ] Add rxvt-unicode terminfo](http://lists.schmorp.de/pipermail/rxvt-unicode/2009q4/001115.html)

Comment: Sorry if my writing is confuse, but I'm not compiling `urxvt`. I'm just compiling `ncurses`. Should I recompile `urxvt` after?

Comment: no - but its sources have a more/less workable terminal description